# Why does Android tablet say "Webpage not available" on UNC path file:///

Tags: android, browser, unc

On a simple network I have machine on 192.168.1.251, where I've shared a directory as "audio".  On another machine in the network, I type "file:///192.168.1.251/audio" in the browser address bar and I get a directory listing (expected result).  But if I open my Android tablet and type the same thing, it says "Webpage not available".  The Android device is on my network (I can get to external web pages and there's no cellular connection...the only connection to the Internet is through my home network).

EDIT 8/29: I added Astro file manager and the SMB module, and I can now copy the files.  But honestly, to not be able to just stream from a Windows box seems insane.  I think I'll just stand-up a little web sever on the Window box!  Geeze!

Comment: I don't think the stock browser recognizes the file:// protocol. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

use `http://192.168.1.251/audio` instead of `file:///192.168.1.251/audio` 
 Dont forget to add internet Permission 
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: VV, I tried the http protocol, but no joy.  The uses-permission thing is for app developers?  I'm just trying to pull up some file from my Windows box.. no coding.